# Geospatial Searches with Searchkick to find users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I just started to use [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) with my Rails web service, for the moment I just testing. I want retrieve users around a certain perimeter of a location with [that](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#geospatial-searches).

For my Test I have a User object (with email, name...), and a Position object (with longitude, latitude and a reference to one User). And User have a has_many relation with Position.

for the moment my Position look like

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
  searchkick locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge location: [latitude, longitude]
  end
end
```

And I try to do a research like

```
Position.search *,  where: {location: {near: [50.632049, 3.068322], within: "100mi"}}
```

But I get the following error

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[positions_development_20140310223244065] failed to find geo_point field [location]]; }]","status":400}
```

I don't know exactly what I have to do. (I'm new to rails, and elastic search)
So if someone can give me a better explanation, I take it ! Thank's

Comment: I've had the same issue aswell and cannot find any solution to this, I keep getting the same error message. Reindexing did not solve anything.

Comment: Update: Got it to work by restarting the opensearch-node & opensearch-dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to reindex after making changes to the `searchkick` or `search_data` methods.

```
Position.reindex
```

Comment: I do, but that ask me an argument, what im suppose to give to reindex ? I try Position.reindex *, but the error still appear

Comment: Call it without the "*". The reindex method doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: finnaly it's ok, I just restarted the rails console. Can you confirm I have to search "*" if I want all positions int the given perimeter?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to use "*" as the query to get all the results that match the where criteria.  Also, in the gist, it looks like a problem with your search_data method.  Try `Position.first.search_data`.